# Invalid file operation in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, file, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I was learning PL/SQL and I have been getting this error as "invalid file operation since long"
The code is as follows:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT on;
CREATE or replace directory DESKTOP as 'C:\Users\Gadre\Desktop';
declare
v1 varchar2(32767);
f1 utl_file.file_type;
begin
f1 :=utl_file.fopen('DESKTOP','test.docx','r');
dbms_output.put_line('HELLO WORLD');
end;
```

The error is:

```
Error report:
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at line 5
29283. 00000 -  "invalid file operation"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
       not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
       operating system.
*Action:   Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
       and if reading, verify that the file exists.
```

The file does exist surely. Plus I am through admin access so I think I do have privileges.

Comment: The code is ok (don't forget to close the file again). Is the database local? If not, then your program looks in the c-drive on the database server. The user running the database service needs to be able to look in the directory.

Comment: The database is local.

Comment: You may have admin privileges, but does the account Oracle is running under? That account needs to be able to see your directory since it's running inside the database.

Comment: Have you issued READ,WRITE grant to your user on the directory?